# Firebase dynamic link open-graph not showing on discord

Tags: react-native, discord, firebase-dynamic-links

I have Firebase dynamic links set up in my react-native app on both IOS and Android, and they work perfectly except for the open-graph part which works on all social platforms but not on Discord. I want it to work on Discord too.

From what I understood from Firebase links docs, the open-graph part is controlled by the `social` property, so I have specified it like this:

```js
  social:
  { title: `Post by Yuniac`,
    descriptionText: 'Jesse Faden, the bureau director',
    imageUrl: 'https://hunt-public.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/hunt_logo.png'
  },
```

When sharing the Firebase dynamic link on social platforms:

- Output on WhatsApp:

[image]

- Output on Discord:

[image]

I tested it on Facebook and Twitter, the links also show a preview there. On Discord, its just a plain link.

What I found online regarding this issue was happening to websites links, not Firebase links generated in a react-native app, so the solutions were often something like:

"You are missing a `<meta>` tag in your `<head>` element that is responsible for the open-graph operation"

Or something similar, but nothing about my specific use case and besides there's no `<meta>` tags in react-native or in a Firebase dynamic link as far as I know, so those didn't help me.

I also stumbled upon people saying that: "Your server might be blocking Discord API" [reference](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/4275#issuecomment-1001182011)
[reference2](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/1731#issuecomment-641062055)

Is this true? and if so how can I unblock it? we use amazon services but I'm not familiar with them. Or what could be the reason our links won't show their preview on Discord? Thanks.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. The preview doesn't appear in discord as well as on Twitter. It works in almost all messaging platforms like WhatsApp, signal, and telegram, and inside the Dms of Instagram. Any update on this?

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I'm afraid the only way to get any sort of help with this is to open a new issue with details on their repo and hopefully they can have some insight on your problem. https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues